# Scan file and replace characters

Tags: java, file

I have created a program that will scan a text file, switch certain characters, and print into another file. I created a program that changed "|" to "\t" AND "\n" to "". There is a run-time error saying, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Nov5.main(Nov5.java:20)"

If anyone knows how to correct this error and get my program running, that would be great. Thanks so much!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

public class Nov5  
{

public static void main( String args[] )
{

    try
    {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "OneRecord.fna" ));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "OneLineRecord.faa" ));

        String line;
        { 
            while ((line = br.readLine () ) != null)
            line = line.replace ( '|' , '\t');
            String replacedString = line.replaceAll ("(\\n)", "");
            bw.write( line );

        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "error" );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Note: you don't use `replacedString` (probably a typo).  So your logic that removes `\n` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add braces to your `while` loop so the statement is not terminated when `replaceAll` occurs

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // increase scope

    line = line.replace('|', '\t');
    String replacedString = line.replaceAll("(\\n)", "");
    bw.write(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your opening brace `{` in the wrong place for your `while` loop.

Without braces following the `while` loop condition, only the first statement after it acts as the body of the loop.  By the time you get to this line

```
String replacedString = line.replaceAll ("(\\n)", "");
```

the entire file has been read and `line` is `null`.  Change

```
{
    while ((line = br.readLine () ) != null)
```

to

```
while ((line = br.readLine () ) != null) {
```